# Nginx - rewrite or internal redirection cycle

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Im using nginx with a very simple configuration, it works for all php sites in the subdirs of /usr/share/nginx/www/.

But now id like to make a new project in a subdirectory with rewrite rules.
So i decide to make a .conf for this beside the default.
But the rewriting is not working cause of the error "rewrite or internal redirection cycle".

default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
    }
}
```

newproject.conf

```
# nginx configuration
autoindex off;

location /newproject/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/newproject/(.+)$ /newproject/index.php?url=$1 break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

This part about fall back to 404 is wrong. Probably you have missed `=404` here, which resulted in redirection cycle (it redirects to `/index.html` again and again).

Please note from [the documentation](http://nginx.org/r/try_files):

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

Comment: even with try_files $uri $uri/ =404; i get the same error in the log.